# BigCartel (Luna Theme): Shipping Rate Calculator not showing in Cart page

Tags: bigcartel

I'm using the Luna Theme with Big Cartel, site here: http://legencrew.bigcartel.com

I'd like my **Cart** page to show the shipping rate calculator which is already included in the theme. The weird thing is that I can successfully preview this feature in the Advanced Customization page, but for some reason it doesn't show up in the "live" website.

I think it is related with the variable "{% if cart.shipping.enabled %}", but I can't figure out what's going on.

I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

All of the variables on your Cart page are working correctly... this is happening because the store is using PayPal Express + Stripe for checkout, so the shipping and discount fields have been moved to the separate Checkout page. If you change the Checkout settings to use PayPal Standard you'll see the shipping and discount fields return. http://help.bigcartel.com/basics/settings/seamless-checkout/